# Raspberry Bluetooth dongle not detected by Android phone

Tags: bluetooth

I want to communicate between android phone and Raspberry via Bluetooth, the Raspberry can discover the android phone [tutorial code](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html) . but the android didn't discover the Bluetooth dongle on RPI neither on ubuntu. on Windows the Android phone discover the dongle (windows installed automatically some kind of driver).

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hciconfig -a hci0
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:98:76:54  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1274 acl:0 sco:0 events:48 errors:0
    TX bytes:458 acl:0 sco:0 commands:47 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0x3e 0x09 0x76 0x80 0x01 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'raspberrypi-0'
    Class: 0x420100
    Service Classes: Networking, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Revision: 0x50
    LMP Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Subversion: 0x3
    Manufacturer: Mitel Semiconductor (16)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to set your BT modem discoverable. Try `hciconfig hci0 piscan` to make it discoverable then `hciconfig hci0 no scan` to ice it after pairing.